# Ubuntu 16.04 unstable USB

Tags: 16.04, usb

I'm experiencing a strange behavior with USB ports on my Ubuntu. Part of the time they work fine, but sometimes they randomly disconnect/reconnect or significantly slow down. This is OK for mouse and keyboard, but this is a problem for other devices: flash drives, wifi adapter, printers.

Below are some details that may help.

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

$ uname -r
4.10.0-37-generic
```

My motherboard is B350 PC MATE.

Also I have a dual boot on the computer with Windows 10 as another system, and on Windows there are no problems with USB.