# Why do Epson R360 and HP5020 USB printers randomly disconnect on various Ubuntu versions (currently 17.10)?

Tags: usb, printing

This has been a constant problem over several years that I just assumed was a sign of my ageing printer slowly giving up or possibly not getting on with linux.

When I try to print a document in a low resolution mode, ie plain paper, mixed text and graphics and standard quality I usually get a print, but not always. My success rate is less with a photo paper, photo, best quality print. The job will start spooling out to the printer then at a random point the printer will stop. The default printer behaviour is to retry the job, causing it to start again where the previous job finished as paper is already in the printer. If the printer behaviour is set to stop I have to switch the printer off in order to eject the sheet as it's cancel button does nothing and it has no other way of performing a form feed.

I generally don't have any system sounds on but the other day I had and noticed a regular alarm notifying me of a USB connect / disconnect. I checked the logs application with searching hardware for USB logs and noticed that the printer was randomly connecting and disconnecting. I swapped in an old HP printer that I sometimes use as a scanner and this showed the same behaviour.

This led me to some articles suggesting laptop power management programmes such as tlp can be a problem or at least a way of solving this as it can be down to autosuspend settings but I don't have it installed.

Comment: found this similar but unanswered question : https://askubuntu.com/questions/970892/ubuntu-16-04-unstable-usb

Answer (score 1):

I was on the correct line with the autosuspend settings and further searches led me to [Cups, troubleshooting USB printers](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CUPS/Troubleshooting#USB_printers) on wiki.archlinux.The solution that worked for me was:

> USB autosuspend
>
> The Linux kernel automatically suspends USB devices when there is driver support and the devices are not in use. This can save power, but some USB printers think that they are disconnected when the kernel suspends the USB port, preventing printing. This can be fixed by deactivating autosuspend for the specific device, see [Power management#USB autosuspend](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management#USB_autosuspend).

This page states:

> USB autosuspend
>
> The Linux kernel can automatically suspend USB devices when they are not in use. This can sometimes save quite a bit of power, however some USB devices are not compatible with USB power saving and start to misbehave (common for USB mice/keyboards). udev rules based on whitelist or blacklist filtering can help to mitigate the problem.

I used Ubuntu's logs app again to find the vendor and product id's (I could have used ctrl-alt-t for a terminal then lsusb for a list of usb devices). I then used gedit to write the following code and save it to the desktop in a file named "50-usb_power_save.rules".

```
# https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management#USB_autosuspend
# insert into etc/udev/rules.d
# blacklist for usb autosuspend
# HP5520 printer scanner
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="03f0", ATTR{idProduct}=="b111", GOTO="power_usb_rules_end"

# Epson R360 printer
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="04b8", ATTR{idProduct}=="082c", GOTO="power_usb_rules_end"

ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", TEST=="power/control", ATTR{power/control}="auto"
LABEL="power_usb_rules_end"
```

I then opened nautilus and ctrl-l to call up an address bar and entered admin: followed by my password (twice?). Next I navigated to etc/udev/rules.d and dropped the file from my desktop to that location. A reboot and so far everything is working fine.

A bit more research indicated linux has an issue with the USB protocols (XHCI, OHCI and EHCI) though I don't pretend to understand what.

> In essence, this is not really a USB hardware problem, but perhaps
> more a Linux problem. The actual fault lies with a misinterpretation
> of the eXtensible Host Controller Interface (xHCI) specification. This
> issue previously did not exist with the older Enhanced Host Controller
> Interface (EHCI) specification. A [«Sharp»](https://plus.google.com/+SarahSharp/posts/RZpndv4BCCD) explanation is available
> online.

from [Fixing USB Autosuspend](http://hamwaves.com/usb.autosuspend/en/index.html) by Serge Y. Stroobandt on hamwaves.com

EDIT:

I spoke too soon. The problem seemed better, but after a while I noticed that the printer was still disconnecting, I think until the printer went on standby itself, then it stayed connected and worked fine. It seems the cure lies in the motherboard settings.

My ASUS F1 A75-V motherboard has 3 settings that seem to be involved in the advanced section, USB Configuration.

1. Legacy USB Support [default = enabled]
2. Legacy USB3.0 Support [enabled]
3. EHCI Hand-off [disabled]

With all three disabled, the printer seems to be working properly and the only thing I can see is that the printer no longer shows up in the BIOS as a mass storage device.
I realise this is an untidy solution and possibly two separate answers but I haven't time at the moment to delve any deeper and back track to narrow down the solution to one particular point.